# predicate spring jpa specification with where in clause on another table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

how to predicate below in clause in spring jpa specification

```
  select * from a where xid in (select id from b where name like '%abc%')
```

where xid is foreign key of b table.

Comment: Don't, use a join instead. THe in will probably be slower then the join and if you m apped it correctly in JPA your query would be as simple as `SELECT a from A a Where a.b.name like ?` Hibernate will take care of the rest.

Comment: How would I do the same in jpa spec.. i want to add more dynamic predicates along with this

Comment: Your question wasn't about multiple predicates but about one. I first would suggest studying the Criteria API on what is available and how to do proper joins/navigate using properties in JPA.